# High Ping Spike Causes Internet Connection to be lost

Tags: networking, lag

So we had recently moved into our grandma's while our house is on the market. She has Armstrong Internet and we upgraded from their Zoom Express (12 Mbps Down, 1 Mbps Up) to their Zoom II (300 Mbps Down, 20 Mbps Up) and they had sent someone out to set it up and gave us a new modem which is the {Arris CM3200A}. It was working okay for the first day or two with the occasional lag spike while I was trying to stream or play games. But now I can't play a game for 5 minutes without my PS4 disconnecting from PSN. We had a technician come out and run all new wires from the pole to the house and then the box on the house to the modem. We also bought a new modem just to see if that was one of the reasons {Arris SurfBoard SB6183} but are still having the problems. And the problem is just a split second ping spike that causes everything to disconnect. The support people keep saying it is on our end and that it could be our router [Netgear Nighthawk AC1900] but I have connected the modem straight into both of our PS4s, Xbox One, and PC. All showing the same problem.[This is the test a ran a little bit ago.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMii3.png)

The only thing I found to be able to show some sort of spike other than just saying there was one was that I ran a ping test in the CMD to the Google servers while I was playing a game and when I got kicked from the game and PSN it said TTL Expired in Transit. Any help is appreciated because I have tried everything I can personally think of. Thank You!

```
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=79ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=110ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 24.101.13.198: TTL expired in transit.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=115
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=115
```

I also ran a trace route to the google server and this is what was shown.

```
Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]

over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  www.routerlogin.com [xxxx]

  2    16 ms     8 ms     8 ms  100.100.67.1

  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  6    12 ms    11 ms    10 ms  static-acs-24-101-13-198.zoominternet.net 
[24.101.13.198]

  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  8    25 ms    23 ms    24 ms  10-1-3.ear3.Washington1.Level3.net 
[4.14.224.173]

  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.

 10    26 ms    29 ms    29 ms  Google-level3-60G.WashingtonDC.Level3.net [4.68.71.186]

 11    28 ms    26 ms    27 ms  108.170.246.1

 12    27 ms    25 ms    27 ms  108.170.231.51

 13    26 ms    27 ms    28 ms  google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: The problem is not a "ping spike", that is a symptom... The tracert is completely normal, often hops in the public internet do not respond to pings. How are your devices connected, wired or wireless? You cannot reliably test this on a wireless connection, it must be wired, and I would begin testing with a PC connected directly to the modem without the router. From the limited information you have though, I would agree this is likely a router issue on your end.

Comment: If I look at the evidence, I come to the same conclusion as you, something is wrong at the internet side that only they can fix. Ask for a mechanic to come over and show them your setup with the device only connected to the modem.

Answer (score 1):

TTL expired messages on pings (not traceroutes) usually indicates a network loop (routing loop). The device reporting the expired TTL is usually a part of the loop. Ask them why their box at 24.101.13.198 is sometimes showing signs of having routing loops.